# Average value over an interval vs. between two points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-theory

For a continuous distribution function F, for some $s>0$, how can I show the following inequality:
$$\large\sup_{0\le r\le s/2}\int_r^{s-r}\frac{F(x)}{s-2r}\text{ d}x \leq \sup_{r\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{F(r)+F(s-r)}{2}\quad$$
In words, the inequality would show that the average value of $F(x)$ over $[r,s-r]$, $r\in[0,\frac{s}{2})$ can always be exceeded by the average value between two points $F(a)$ and $F(s-a)$, for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

To be clear, I assume $F:\Bbb R\to[0,1]$ is continuous and nondecreasing with $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 stock messages aren't always appropriate. What they're asking is clear: "how can I show the following inequality?"

Comment: To the OP: how do you define "continuous distribution function"? A continuous $F:\Bbb R\to[0,1]$ with $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$ and $F$ is nondecreasing?

Comment: @Fshrike Yes exactly.

Comment: @FShrike Ah sorry about that, I wasn't exactly able to tell, but now that I see that, I am extremely sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that after the change of variables $u = s-x$, we have \begin{align*}
\int_r^{s-r} \frac{F(x)}{s-2r}dx &= -\int_{s-r}^r\frac{F(s-u)}{s-2r}du \\
&= \int_r^{s-r} \frac{F(s-x)}{s-2r}dx, \end{align*}
so \begin{align*}\int_r^{s-r} \frac{F(x)}{s-2r}dx &= \frac 12 \left( \int_r^{s-r} \frac{F(x) + F(s-x)}{s-2r}dx\right) \\ 
&\le \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}}  \frac 12 \left( \int_r^{s-r} \frac{F(y) + F(s-y)}{s-2r}dx\right) \\
&= \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{F(y)+F(s-y)}{2}.
\end{align*}
Taking the sup over $r \in [0,\frac{s}{2}]$ on the LHS yields the result.

Comment: (+1) That was clever!

Comment: Ah nice approach, thank you!